# WP7 MessageBox stops vibrate from happening when displayed

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, messagebox

I am having some trouble getting my application to cause the phone to vibrate and play a sound at the same time as displaying a messagebox.

I have managed to get the sound to repeat whilst the messagebox is displayed but I cannot get the vibrate to work at the same time as a messagebox.

I currently use the following code to play a vibrating pulse:

```
public void vibrate()
    {
        DispatcherTimer vibrateTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        vibrateTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(vibrateTimer_Tick);
        vibrateTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        vibrateTimer.Start();
    }

    void vibrateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vc.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
    }
```

I then call the vibrate() method. If I call a simple vibrate that plays for say 10 seconds without pulsing then this works however the pulse does not.

Is there anyway around this so I can play a pulsing vibrate while the message box has been displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XNA's [Guide.BeginShowMessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940233.aspx) as the message box instead. I believe this doesn't vibrate or play a sound, so you should have full control.

Comment: and this can be used in a silverlight application? Thanks

Comment: @James Mundy - Yes it can http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/75114.aspx There's also a `Message Prompt` in the Coding 4 Fun toolkit http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/